# Which alternatives to OpenSSL do I have to calculate a SHA-256 hash?

Tags: command-line, macos, openssl, encryption

How to calculate [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) on a file to generate a [256-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/256-bit) result (SHA-256)?

In the old days we used the [openssl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) tool. I have heard that after terrible security vulnerabilities with openssl, the world has moved on to alternative tools. Does macOS Sierra ship with alternatives to openssl? What is the modern approach to running a SHA-256 hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `shasum`

You can just use [shasum](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/shasum.1.html):

```
shasum -a 256 FILE.txt
```

- The `shasum` is the name of the command.
- The `-a` option means *algorithm*.
- The `256` specifies use of the 256-bit algorithm.

Comment: That linked page for documentation seems to be old and is marked 'legacy'. I'm not able to find more recent doc on Darwin man pages. Perhaps Apple’s implementation of `shasum` matches the FreeBSD implemantation [documented here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=shasum&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: Yeah it’s the same. But `shasum` is a command that just gets installed as part of any standard Perl install, along with the `perl` command and whatnot. As far as the online docs being marked 'legacy' I think that’s only because Apple maybe no longer maintains an online version of any OS X `man` pages. But anyway, `shasum` hasn’t changed in a long time—nor is it likely to any time soon I guess. It’s just a Perl implementation of the various hashing algorithms.